# Laravel hasMany as many hasOne

Tags: php, laravel

For example, i have Post and Comment models. When i load hasMany relation, i want to get separate parent item for each relation item.

**Post.php:**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

**Comment.php:**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

When i load post with comments

```
Post::where('title', 'LIKE', search) 
    ->orWhereHas('comments', function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('text', 'LIKE', $search) 
    })
    ->paginate();
```

results looks like this

```
[
    {
        post_id: 1,
        comments: [
            {
                comment_id: 1
                post_id: 1
            },
            {
                comment_id: 2
                post_id: 1
            },
            {
                comment_id: 3
                post_id: 1
            },
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

but i need it to look like this (separate Post for each Comment).

```
[
    {
        post_id: 1,
        comments: [
            {
                comment_id: 1
                post_id: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        post_id: 1,
        comments: [
            {
                comment_id: 2
                post_id: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        post_id: 1,
        comments: [
            {
                comment_id: 3
                post_id: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Can i do it with Laravel?

Comment: Why do you want to have the same `Post` in your JSON multiple times, each with an array of 1 `Comment`? You can transform your result before returning it, but I still don't understand why... Or, you can query from the opposite: `$comments = Comment::with('post')->where('post_id', $id)->get()`;

Comment: @TimLewis I need to search in post title and comments text and output it as post-comment pairs

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that... Can you show your code and why the output of 1 Post with many Comments doesn't work? Or, like I said, reverse the querying; `Comment -> Post` is `1-1` (a pair), but `Post -> Comment` is `1-∞` (not a "pair").

Comment: @TimLewis i need it to look similar to stackoverflow search results (see example https://prnt.sc/94SgDvFM9qoz).

Answer (score 0):

You are now retrieving posts with their comments, but from what I understand you actually want to retrieve comments from specific posts.

The only difficulty then is specifying which posts to load the comments from, but this might do the trick:

```
$comments = Comment::whereHas('post', function($query) use ($ids) {
        $query->whereIn('post_id', $ids);
    })
    ->with('post')
    ->get();
```

<strike>(two small errors in the Comment model need to be fixed first: rename the function from `comments()` to `post()` and change `this` to `$this`)</strike>

Here's a simple foreach to test the result:

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo 'Post ' . $comment->post->id . ' comment' . $comment->id . '<br>';
}
```

If you absolutely need the result in the format you show in the JSON data some extra work is needed, but it should not be necessary to do that to get the output as you show in the image you linked in the comments.

UPDATE (because the user changed the question):

Searching by comment text (instead of post-id) makes the query even easier; now no nested query is necessary at all:

```
$comments = Comment::where('text', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->with('post')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But what if i use search in my query? (See updated query in my post)

Comment: Why do you retrieve by `Post::` when what you actually want is an item per comment? I added an update, but please post a new question next time instead of changing your current one.